# How can I get Top Location from Google Analytics API?

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytics PHP client library. Is there any way to get the city from which highest number of page views reported?
Thanks

Comment: As documentation suggests, If the answer is correct, mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `dimensions` and `metrics` properties:

```
$topCity = $ga->getReport(
        array('dimensions'=>urlencode('ga:city'),
            'metrics'=>urlencode('ga:pageviews'),
            'max-results' => 1,  
            'sort'=>'-ga:pageviews',
            )
        );
```